# How to findallby'attributes'()?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity

```
class Developer extends CustomUser
{

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="unsubscribe_token", type="string", length=60, nullable=true)
     */
     private $unsubscribeToken;


    // ...
}
```

and entity CustomUser

```
class CustomUser
 {

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=25, nullable=false)
 * Assert\NotBlank
 */
protected $roles = 'ROLE_AGENT';


    // ...
}
```

And a action

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $role = 'ROLE_FREELANCER';

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $all_developer = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')->findAll();

            $dev_freelancer = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')
                    ->findBy(array('roles' => $role, 'level' => 'Middle', 'unsubscribeToken' => ??));
    return $this->render('ArtelProfileBundle:Dachboard:index.html.twig', array(
        'developer' => $all_developer,
        'developer_freelancer' => $dev_freelancer,
    ));
}

  public function getDevelopersWithRoleAndNullToken($role)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')
        ->where('d.role = :role')
        ->andWhere('d.token IS NOT NULL')
        ->setParameter('role', $role)
        ->getQuery();
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
    return $results;
}
```

[Semantical Error] line 0, col 53 near 'role = :role': Error: Class Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer has no field or association named role

In my database many developer, I want find all developers who have roles freelancer and unsubscribeToken nut null example. How I do that?

Comment: `->findBy(array(**field** => **value**))` will do the trick.

Comment: thanks, very simple, hot that do if using createQueryBuilder() ?

Comment: If you want to use the queryBuilder you have two ways, create the query builder in the controller or create the method in a repository file and then call it from the controller (is the one that I recommend you, the controller shouldn't know this logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindBy will find all of them, FindOneBy just one

So,

Considering that your field is called **role** you have to do this

```
$dev_freelancer = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')->findBy(array('role' => $role));
```

Here you have the documentation

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions

If you want to find developers which rol is freelance and token is not null you should do it through QueryBuilder, there's no way to findBy not null value

something like this

```
    public function getDevelopersWithRoleAndNullToken($role)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

        $qb
            ->select('d')
            ->from('ArtelProfileBundle\Entity\Developer', 'd')
            ->where('d.roles = :role')
            ->andWhere('d.unsubscribeToken IS NOT NULL')
            ->setParameter('role', $role)
            ->getQuery();

        return $qb->getResult();
    }
```

And then from the controller...

```
$developersRolAndNullToken = $em->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer')->getDevelopersWithRoleAndNullToken($role);
```

Comment: if I have two field - role and token and I want all user who has role freelancer and token nut null ?

Comment: Oh sorry not null, you cannot do it in findBy, I will update my answer

Comment: no find getResult I fix

`        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $results = $query->getResult();`
but my field role in class CustomUser and
class Developer extends CustomUser
and now 

`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 53 near 'role = :role': Error: Class Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer has no field or association named role `

Comment: sorry my fault, try now. Your field is called roles not role and unsubscribeToken rather than token

Comment: You should call it role, it's just a string with one rol per developer otherwise is confusing

Comment: I know whatnot see field role??
`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 53 near 'role = :role': Error: Class Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer has no field or association named role`

Comment: Try again, I have updated the answer, I have changed role with roles and token with unsubscribeToken I didn't realise that you have it like this, let me know if it's working

Comment: I try 
`
  public function getDevelopersWithRoleAndNullToken($role)
    {

        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

        $qb
            ->select('d')
            ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')
            ->where('d.role = :role')
            ->andWhere('d.token IS NOT NULL')
            ->setParameter('role', $role)
            ->getQuery();
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $results = $query->getResult();

        return $results;
    }
`

Comment: public function getDevelopersWithRoleAndNullToken($role)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

        $qb
            ->select('d')
            ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')
            ->where('d.roles = :role')
            ->andWhere('d.unsubscribeToken IS NOT NULL')
            ->setParameter('role', $role)
            ->getQuery();

        return $qb->getResult();
    }

Comment: I update answer, Igave two entity Developer extends SUser, SUser have field role but method not see this field 
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 53 near 'role = :role': Error: Class Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Developer has no field or association named role

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82810/discussion-between-fernando-caraballo-and-shuba-ivan).